# Strange left-over vertices after using a boolean to intersect two objects

Tags: vertices, boolean-modifier, intersection

I have this simple wall that has 64x16 subdivisions

[image: simple wall]

and then an arched wall (created by beveling a wall of the same size but with only 8 vertices).

[image: arched wall]

Now I want to intersect them using a boolean so that I can have the arched wall but with the even subdivision of the first one.

It kinda works but then I see these vertices by the arched edge, and I don't know what to do to improve this modifier so that it doesn't do that

[image: weird vertices]

I am thinking, maybe the vertices of the beveled wall should have a specific amount that could work with the subdivided wall so that the geometry is build correctly.

The beveled wall looks like this in edit mode (it has 32 edges on top and they should connect in a proper manner to the vertices of the final result)

[image: beveled in edit mode]

Comment: Hello could you please show a reference image of the object you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added more images. I want the second image but the big faces should have the divisions of the first image. Basically I want an arched wall but with clean and even geometry

Comment: Why do you need this 64x16 subdivision? You could use the Knife Project tool if you really want to cut the wall with the other shape

Comment: In general I would agree with @moonboots, there are better ways to do this than the _Boolean_ modifier. However, when you are doing it this way, make sure the faces of the 64×16 wall are not lying in the same plane as the front or back face of the arched wall - having them in the same location can result in weird artifacts (due to precision issues I guess), so make sure the subdivided wall lies between the outside (front/back) faces of the arched wall. And sometimes switching the _Boolean_ modifier from _Solver_ > _Exact_ to _Fast_ can help as well.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, indeed, that seems to improve it, not having the faces overlapped. I will try a few more tweaks to see if I can pull it of in one step